# Worse performance only using 2 cores

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I made a program that calculates Armstrong numbers in a certain range, the problem is that the performance is worse than the serial implementation only when using 2 processors

This is the serial code:

```
import sys
import random
from time import perf_counter as pc
import datetime
import time
ARRAYSIZE = int(sys.argv[1])


numbers = [i for i in range(1, ARRAYSIZE+1)]
random.shuffle(numbers)

start_time = time.time()
armstrong = []
for i in numbers:
    num = i
    result = 0
    n = len(str(i))
    while(i != 0):
        digit = i % 10
        result += digit**n
        i //= 10
    if num == result:
        armstrong.append(num)
armstrong.sort()
elapsed_time = (time.time() - start_time)
print(f"Serial time (Shuffle): {elapsed_time}")
```

Basically, it checks for each number in the array if it's an Armstrong number or not.

This is the parallel code:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import random
import sys
import timeit

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()
MASTER = 0
WORKERS = size - 1
ARRAYSIZE = int(sys.argv[1])

CHUNKSIZE = ARRAYSIZE//WORKERS


if rank == MASTER:
    master_time = timeit.default_timer()
    array = []
    for i in range(ARRAYSIZE):
        array.append(i+1)
    random.shuffle(array)
    for i in range(WORKERS):
        sub_array = []
        for j in range(CHUNKSIZE):
            sub_array.append(array[j])
        comm.send(sub_array, dest=(i+1), tag=1)
        array = array[CHUNKSIZE:len(array)]
    armstrong = []
    for i in array:
        num = i
        result = 0
        n = len(str(num))
        while(i != 0):
            digit = i % 10
            result += digit**n
            i //= 10
        if num == result:
            armstrong.extend(num)
    for i in range(WORKERS):
        get_armstrong_numbers = comm.recv(tag=2)
        armstrong.extend(get_armstrong_numbers)
    armstrong.sort()
    print(f'Master Time (Shuffle): {timeit.default_timer() - master_time}')


elif rank != MASTER:
    worker_time = timeit.default_timer()
    receive = comm.recv(source=0, tag=1)
    armstrong_numbers = []
    for i in range(CHUNKSIZE):
        num = receive[i]
        result = 0
        n = len(str(num))
        while(receive[i] != 0):
            digit = receive[i] % 10
            result += digit**n
            receive[i] //= 10
        if num == result:
            armstrong_numbers.append(num)
    comm.send(armstrong_numbers, dest=0, tag=2)
    print(f'Worker time (Shuffle): {timeit.default_timer() - worker_time}')
```

What the parallel program does is to divide the initial array into parts to be assigned to the various workers and a part is assigned to the master. Once finished, the workers send their part to the master and the master goes to merge, sort and print the results.

Here's some times: (I just copied and pasted my terminal)

```
PS C:\Users\danil\Desktop\Armstrong Numbers\2 Cores - Intermediate Times> python .\serial_shuffle.py 10000000    
Serial time (Shuffle): 27.026000261306763
PS C:\Users\danil\Desktop\Armstrong Numbers\2 Cores - Intermediate Times> mpiexec -n 2 python .\Shuffle.py 10000000
Master Time (Shuffle): 39.5854112
PS C:\Users\danil\Desktop\Armstrong Numbers\2 Cores - Intermediate Times> mpiexec -n 3 python .\Shuffle.py 10000000
Worker time (Shuffle): 23.1734209
Worker time (Shuffle): 25.0732174
Master Time (Shuffle): 25.073847100000002
Worker time (Shuffle): 17.7299418
Worker time (Shuffle): 19.547413000000002
Worker time (Shuffle): 20.8562403
Master Time (Shuffle): 20.8567713
PS C:\Users\danil\Desktop\Armstrong Numbers\2 Cores - Intermediate Times> mpiexec -n 5 python .\Shuffle.py 10000000
Worker time (Shuffle): 14.8727631
Worker time (Shuffle): 16.3137905
Worker time (Shuffle): 17.071894099999998
Worker time (Shuffle): 18.0240944
Master Time (Shuffle): 18.0242909
PS C:\Users\danil\Desktop\Armstrong Numbers\2 Cores - Intermediate Times> mpiexec -n 6 python .\Shuffle.py 10000000
Worker time (Shuffle): 13.0210344
Worker time (Shuffle): 14.223855599999998
Worker time (Shuffle): 15.3327299
Worker time (Shuffle): 16.0194109
Worker time (Shuffle): 16.786164199999998
Master Time (Shuffle): 16.785847299999997
```

Some points:

1. Complexity of sort: irrelevant, I have the same behavior if I don't shuffle (and consequently) don't sort the array
2. As you can see, this only happens with *-n 2*
3. Same behavior with all kind of numbers: from 1000 to 250000000
4. I know that I/O operations (like prints) are inhibitors for the parallelization
5. I use the same method to check for an Armstrong Number

Comment: You should profile your application to figure out how much time is spend in communication (e.g. overhead) and in computation (more tasks means less work per task means shorter time to result). I guess 2 MPI tasks is not enough to compensate the communication overhead.

Comment: Yeah i think so. How can i check the time required for the communication?

Comment: Use a tool such as VaMPIr, ITAC or MAP. Or do it manually with `MPI_Wtime()`

Comment: Thanks, i'll try